# Круговая зависимость в webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Подскажите как избавиться от круговой зависимости, я импортирую все шаги в allStep и использую  allStep в goToStep, НО goToStep используется в каждом шаге внтури(

Проблема

step-1.js -> go-to-step.js -> all-step.js -> step-1.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-wave-vxt0v?file=/go-to-step.js